# Can't detach security group from ENI and remove VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I created a Cloud Formation stack for Kubernetes cluster and then deleted it and noticed that the VPC and ENI were left undeleted so wanted to remove the VPC but it wouldn't let me because an ENI is attached to it.

I tried deleting the ENI but it wouldn't let me because a security group is attached to it.

Tried to remove the security group and assign a default VPS SG but it says I don't have permissions to do that.

I tried looking up the security group using aws cli but it says that the security group doesn't exist. I can see it right now in my console so why does it say it doesn't exist? I'm stuck.

How do I remove the ENI, VPC and the security group?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that AWS CLI uses default region from profile config so I added `--region ...`  flag to the command and that solved my problem. Lesson learned the hard way.